# VLC Activation Issue under Gnome 3.20

Tags: linux, gnome, vlc

I am able to 'double click' on any Video File and it will open and play properly.  If I click on the Icon (either under favorites or on my desktop) nothing happens.  They both are using /usr/bin/vlc but one works and one does not. The application is unique and has -rwxr-xr-x permissions and is version:

```
VLC media player 3.0.0-git Vetinari (revision
2.2.0-git-13711-g25320d090f) VLC version 3.0.0-git Vetinari (2.2.0-git-13711-g25320d090f) Compiled by mockbuild on buildvm-01.online.rpmfusion.net (Jul 31 2017 13:48:13) Compiler: gcc version 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1) (GCC)
```

It is running on:

```
Linux PANTRY 4.11.12-100.fc24.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jul 21 17:35:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas would be appreciated...
Robert

Comment: What output do you get if you try running it with `vlc whatever.mp4` from the command line?

Comment: $ vlc VID_00000093.mp4
VLC media player 3.0.0-git Vetinari (revision 2.2.0-git-13711-g25320d090f)
[000000370cc991c0] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[000000370cd2c660] core playlist: end of playlist, exiting
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread

[me@PLG-F24 186 ~/Videos]    It actually ran the video OK.

Comment: Looks like a problem with `vlc.desktop` file. Look for this file in `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/` directories and tell me, what is in the `Exec=` option.